# cannot convert from 'object' to 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create a login form with MySQL connection and i have so far done well but am having trouble with one part where I get this error is VS2019
`cannot convert from 'object' to 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType'`

This is the code im using in an array

```
private bool ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DB db = new DB();

    String username = textBoxUsername.Text;
    String password = textBoxPassword.Text;

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = @usn and 'password' = @pass");

    command.Parameters.Add("@usn", VarChar).Value = textBoxUsername.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@pass", VarChar).Value = textBoxPassword.Text;

    adapter.SelectCommand = command;

    adapter.Fill(table);

    // check if this username already exists in the database
    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is with the `VarChar` part it doesn't seem to recognize `VarChar`.. everything else seems to be recognised but not `VarChar`... please help. I have tried googling the error and trying the solutions mentioned like `("@usn", VarChar, 15)` and nothing is actually making `VarChar` a recognized MySQL object.

Comment: `\`username\` = @usn and 'password'` Why are the two column names surrounded by different characters?

Comment: Check the syntax as offered by Intellisense or read the error message carefully - it needs a `MySqlDbType` such as `MySqlDbType.String`

Comment: I am following a YT tutorial and i am having to change code as I go along as some stuff doesn't work in mine where does in theirs xD the link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhkHvEE-5W0 and the time I am at is 46:42 atm

Comment: i right clicked onand chose go to definitio and i got ```cannot navigate to the symbol under the carat```

Comment: How did you end up using VarChar?

Comment: Instead of just `VarChar` try using `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar`

Comment: I am following  aa YT tutorial for a login form as posted in the replies already and its what he used... as am still learning the language

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya Instead of just VarChar try using ```MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar``` OMFG that worked thsanks

Comment: What is the corresponding field design in your database? Can you provide it?

Answer (score 0):

Let try with *AddWithValue* to resolve your issue.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usn", textBoxUsername.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textBoxPassword.Text);
```

Comment: The OP has already solved their issue as per their last comment.